# comparing three variables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have three integer variables: **firstCount**, **secondCount**, **thirdCount**. I need to compare it and to output the result. I'm bad at SQL, but C# code is something like this:

```
if(firstCount == secondCount == thirdCount)
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Comment: That wouldn't work in C#, and it won't work in SQL. You need `if (firstCount == secondCount && secondCount == thirdCount)...`. As it stands, you're doing `((firstCount == secondCount) == thirdCount)`, which evaluates to `(boolean true/false) == thirdCount`.

Comment: Are nulls to be treated as equal or unequal?

Comment: @Martin Smith there is not null values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is one way to do it but after reading @meagar's comment, I find that solution to be more elegant. Just waiting for him to turn it into an answer...

```
DECLARE @firstcount INTEGER
DECLARE @secondcount INTEGER
DECLARE @thirdcount INTEGER

SET @firstcount = 1
SET @secondcount = 2
SET @thirdcount = 3

IF @firstcount <> @secondcount SELECT 0
ELSE IF @secondcount <> @thirdcount SELECT 0
ELSE SELECT 1
```

Comment: You forgot to compare `@firstcount` to `@thirdcount`.

Comment: @norlando - I didn't forgot, that is implicitly taken care of.

Comment: is there any way to do it with the 'select' construction? I must return it to c# code but not to the message window

Comment: @Wachburn - replace the PRINT statements with SELECT and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 4):

One way (2008 syntax).

```
SELECT CAST(CASE
         WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT C) = 1 THEN 1
         ELSE 0
       END AS BIT)
FROM   (VALUES (@firstCount),
               (@secondCount),
               (@thirdCount)) t (C)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
    declare @first int
        , @second int
        , @third int

        select @first = 0
            , @second = 0
            , @third = 0

select case when (@first = @second) AND (@second = @third) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Comment: +1 In my personal opinion, this is the best solution in terms of readability and maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

You are wanting to say If Firstcount is equal to second count, and secondcount is equal to third count return true.

You can just do

```
DECLARE @a INT = 2
DECLARE @b INT = 2
DECLARE @c INT = 2

IF (@a = @b AND @a = @c)
BEGIN
    Print('true')
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    Print('false')
END
```

Although it makes no difference you dont need to test `B = C` because `A = C` is exactly the same thing since all 3 values have to be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Try the code ,

```
if ( (firstCount = secondCount) and (secondCount = thirdCount) and (firstCount = ThirdCount) )
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Mod

```
Declare @totalsvalidation decimal  
select @TotalsValidation = (sum(detail) *100 + sum(header_total)*100 + sum(footer_total)*100) %3   from Mytable
 
IF @TotalsValidation = 0.00 
Begin 
 continue to processing
End 
If @totalsValidation <> 0.00

Begin 
raise error send email 
End
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).